# Python app cannot print result

Tags: python

I have installed python on windows and i have written a function but this function just won't print a thing on the screen

```
def rock(x,y):
    result = x * y
    return result

    print(rock(440,400))
```

What is the reason why this script isn't printing the result?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the `print` function is *inside* the function definition. Do this instead:

```
def rock(x,y):
    result = x * y
    return result

print(rock(440,400))
```

Comment: Has this got to do with `pep8`?

Comment: @javamq Nope, this is just normal python syntax, anything _inside_ a function definition block is considered a part of the function.

Comment: Worth noting that a `print` inside a function will generally work, but this one is *after* the `return` statement and is therefore never reached

Comment: @GamesBrainiac @Deestan This block thing,where can i study it?.I went straight to `pep8` and overlooked definition blocks et al.

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive; that means that indentation actually carries a meaning. When in other languages you use some characters to mark up blocks (e.g. curly braces `{ }`), in Python, you just properly indent that block.

Comment: is there a reference on blocks that i can read?

Comment: The [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is probably a good place to start. Section 3 spends some time discussing indentation.